# Adding static route with DHCP

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have a dilemna. 
I wish to add a permanent static route to a machine that is using DHCP to obtain the DNS server address. To further explain, when I use DHCP I must request both IP address and DNS information, but then the IP address is not set up until late in the boot and the process to add the static route that is in the "interfaces" file fails and no static route is added.
However I can find no means to set a static IP address but still be able to request the DNS server information through DHCP.

Comment: Would it work to set a static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces` and simply use the gateway (router?) address for the DNS nameserver?

Answer (score 0):

Most DHCP providers (routers etc) have the option to set a 'reserved address' - a pairing of MAC address to IP Address.

It would be an option in the DHCP setup somewhere - this may vary by device.

You then don't have to set up static addressing on the local machine, it applies for a DHCP address & gets it's reserved address every time.

Comment: I must use static addressing, as this appears the only way to activate a permanent static route. If you have a workaround for the permanent static route issue with DHCP, then I would use DHCP.

Comment: I am using VirtualBox to run these machines, and the DHCP server of VirtualBox is simple and does not support DNS, rather it gives the DNS address of the host machine, which will vary.